# Error In Custom Creatd Perl Plugin ?? Permission Denied

Tags: perl, nagios

i am new to perl so need you help alot i try to create perl plugin using this link,

http://itwarriors.com/?p=1

i have created file name check_test.pl in (/usr/local/nagios/libexec),

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Getopt::Long qw(:config no_ignore_case);
my ($host, $server, $instances);
my $result = GetOptions(
“H|host=s” => \$host,
“s|server=s” => \$server,
“i|instances=s” => \$instances,
);
print “My host IP is $host\n”;
print “My Server IP is $server\n”;
print “Times Server found are $instances\n”;
```

and after getting this error,

[root@localhost libexec]# ./check_test.pl -h 192.168.1.101 -s 192.168.1.110 -i 2
bash: ./check_test.pl: Permission denied

i try to add ,

```
# 'check_test' command definition
define command{
command_name    check_test
command_line    $USER1$/check_test.pl -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -s 12489 
}
```

command in command.cfg

instead of that i am getting error permission denied please hekp for this error that what actually error is???

Comment: Alter the permissions of the script so that Nagios--or whatever other service that needs to run the script--can run the script.

Comment: how do i alter the permissions of the script ?? :(

Comment: Take a look at `man chmod` (in particular, the first manual page).

Comment: man chmod ??? what is it i haven't understand please let me know in detail about it !

Comment: Type `man chmod` on the command line and hit enter.  If you're presented with a choice as to which manual page (aka man page) to use, select the first one.  Documentation is your friend.  Use it.

Comment: now i am getting error "unrecognize character \xE2 at./check_test.pl line 6" ???  what is the error my code is define above???

Comment: Does line 6 of your script correspond to the sixth line of code that you've posted above?

Comment: What is the encoding of `check_test.pl`?  Try `use utf8;`.

Comment: i have got the error my code is fine actually i copy paste it thats why is was giving error but when i type it it goes fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script needs execution permission:

```
chmod +x check_test.pl
```